# Accessing JPA application in different DBs using different hibernate.cfg files

Tags: hibernate

I have developed my application using Mysql 5.5. I want to run it on Oracle DB now.How can 
i do it? Read about using EntityManager,but don't have much idea about it. Can I do it using multiple hibernate.cfg files?

Answer (score 0):

Explore Spring JPA which supports multiple DB persistence.